# Auth laravel con una tabla diferente y campos diferentes

Tags: laravel, eloquent, autenticación

Estoy intentando hacer una autenticación en mi proyecto con una tabla diferente la cual se llama **Usuarios**  en lugar de **users** que es la que tiene por defecto Laravel, tambien quisiera iniciar sesion con el numero de **identificacion** en lugar del **"correo"** y que en lugar de **password** inicie con un campo llamado **"contrasena"** , ya ejecute el comando `php artisan make:auth` , pero no se que debo cambiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero creas un `controller` llamado **AuthController** con el comando `php artisan make:controller AuthController`

Luego creas un `modelo` llamado **Usuarios** con el comando `php artisan make:model Usuarios`

Define tu archivo de ruta de esta manera:

**Route**

```
    Route::get( '/', 'AuthController@loginForm' )->name( 'login' );
    Route::post( 'login', 'AuthController@loginPost' )->name( 'login_post' );
    Route::get( 'logout', 'AuthController@logoutGet' )->name( 'logout' );
    Route::post( 'logout', 'AuthController@logoutPost' )->name( 'logout_post' );
```

**Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;

public function loginForm() {
            return view( 'auth.login' );
        }

        public function loginPost( Request $request ) {

            $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), [
                'no_id' => 'required|min:3',
                'contrasena' => 'required|min:3',
            ] );

            if ( $validator->fails() ) {
                return response()->json( [ 'success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->errors() ] );
            }


            if ( Auth::attempt( [ 'no_id' => $request->no_id, 'contrasena' => $request->contrasena ]) ) {

                    return response()->json( [ 'success' => true, 'message' => 'Acceso satisfactorio' ] );

             } else {
                return response()->json( [ 'success' => false, 'message' => 'Usuario o contraseña incorrecta' ] );
            }
        }

        //Cerrar session
        public function logoutGet() {

            Auth::logout();

            return redirect( '/' );
        }

        //Cerrar session
        public function logoutPost() {

            Auth::logout();

            return redirect( '/' );
        }
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('login_post') }}" method="post" id="login_form">

    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="form-group-no_id">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_id" id="no_id"
        placeholder="Usuario" autofocus required>
        <div class='errors help-block _no_id'></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="form-group-contrasena">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" placeholder="Contrasenna"
        minlength="6" required>
        <div class='errors help-block _contrasena'></div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="btn_login" value="Login">Login</button>

</form>
```

Luego defines al final del formulario este `script`

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#login_form').on('submit',function(){
            var $form = $(this)
                //Limpiar errores
                $('.errors').hide()
                $('.errors').children('message').html('')

                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    type:$form.attr('method'),
                    data:$form.serialize(),
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $('#no_id,#contrasena').attr('class','form-control disabled').attr('disabled','disabled')
                        $('#btn_login').attr('class','btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat disabled').attr('disabled','disabled')
                        $('body').attr('style','cursor:wait')
                        $('#login_form').css("opacity",".5");
                    },
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function($data){
                        //Si el acceso es insatisfactorio
                        if($data.success==false){
                            if($data.errors){
                                //Mostrar los errores en los campos del login
                                $.each($data.errors,function($i,$value){
                                    $('._'+$i).html($value).fadeIn('fast');
                                    $('#form-group-'+$i).attr('class','form-group has-feedback has-error')
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        $('._'+$i).fadeOut()
                                        $('#form-group-'+$i).attr('class','form-group has-feedback')
                                    },5000)
                                })
                            }else{
                                //Mensaje de Error general
                                alert($data.message)
                            }
                            $('#no_id,#contrasena').removeAttr('disabled').attr('class','form-control')
                            $('#btn_login').attr('class','btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat').removeAttr('disabled')
                            $('#btn_login').children('i').attr('class', 'fa fa-sign-in')
                            $('body').attr('style','cursor:default')
                            $('#login_form').css("opacity","");
                        }else{
                            //Mensaje de Acceso satisfactorio
                            alert($data.message)

                            setTimeout(function(){
                                window.location = '{{ url('/home') }}' //aki defines la ruta que deseas ir despues de que hagas login
                            },1500)
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
    })
```

En la clase `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`  es donde se editan los valores de los campos `username` y `password`, donde los cambiaremos a `no_id` y `contrasena`

```
 public function username()
    {
        return 'no_id';
    }

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'contrasena' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

**Respondiendo la duda del OP**

Modifica el `modelo` **User** en la lista de `Provider` en `config/auth.php`. En el `User Provider`

`'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class, //aki cambias el modelo User por tu modelo Usuarios 
        ],`

esto hará que su `modelo` de `Usuario` esté disponible y sea el usado.

Comment: @Y1L1 todo esta muy claro y entendible , execto donde en lugar de usar la tabla **user** uso la tabla que yo cree **usuarios** , no veo deonde esta esa parte en el codifo que mandastes

Comment: Edite mi repuesta poniendote al final como puedes cambiar el uso de la tabla User por Usuarios.